# Saving data in my OSX application

Tags: cocoa, datastore

I have looked at various ways of saving data. I have a 'Products' class which has properties such as ID, Name, and Price. What is the bast way to save this data as new products are added to the application? Should I be looking at databases, arrays, or both, or something else?

Comment: Save data for what platform?  Skipping details won't get you anywhere.

Comment: @TBlue: Question's title says "OS X".

Answer (score 3):

*Temporary* : Arrays, Dictionary with a model.

*Permanent* : Plist, CoreData-SQLite, Server(ex-Java)-Database(MySQL, Oracle...).

Even for permanent you need Arrays/Dictionaries of model.

Now choice is yours, how you want to proceed.